# Request body is null for POST request in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the below code. when I make a Post request via Postman I get `req.body` as undefined.

Post Request is `http://localhost:1702/es`.

Body:

```
{
  "ip_a":"191.X.X.XX",
  "pkts":34    
}
```

and `Content-Type:"application/json"`. I also used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but got the same result.

My app.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var es=require('./routes/es');
var app = express();
app.post('/es',es.postesdata);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

And my file where I am receiving a request body null is:

```
exports.postesdata=function(req,res){

    var body=req.body;

    console.log(body);//Getting Undefined here 

}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`express` runs middleware in order try:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/es',es.postesdata);
```

Comment: Got my mistake I had app.post first before app.use which resulted in body as undefined.Thank you

Comment: I had the same issue. I moved the above code exactly below the app getting initialise like below                                                                
                                                                                                         
 //create express app
var app = express();
// parse the request of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

// parse requests of content-type -application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());